Git good practice : Merge changes on some files, ignore other new files
Using git 2.42.0.windows.2 and the Bash console, I have a branch H with some changes to module V (some of which are coming from another branch O), a new module L, and a module C that is from that same other branch O but which I don't use.
The main branch, D, has an older version of V, but neither L nor C. I want to update D so it has the latest V and L, but not C. This would yield a new commit, which I will call D1.
Is it a meaningful thing to do in terms of Git ? What is the best way to do this ? Would my branch H then be considered a parent of D1, even though my branch H has module C, yet D1 doesn't ?
The aim is for me to continue my work on module L right from the main branch D, bringing the latest version of V but ignoring module C (which whoever is working on branch O will later bring to D, but on their own terms and in their own time).
---------------------------------------------------------------------D
         \
          ------------------------------- O
             (work on V, creation of C)    \
                                            -------------------------------- H
                                                 (work on V, creation of L)
                    

Is this where cherry-picking comes in ? Any other alternatives ?

git merge --no-commit?  You can review the changes and remove C from the staging area then do a git commit.  This will probably make the future merge more difficult for whomever is working on C since I think it'll look like it was just deleted, but they can still make it work.

if your changes never touch anything related to C, maybe you can rebase like this git checkout H; git rebase --onto D O, meaning that you reapply every commit in H onto D, starting from the next commit after O

/\ nevermind my comment above, it's wrong, because you need the work on V part of the O branch, so you probably need the @StephenNewell solution

What you want to do is not meaningful with Git. A merge commit is not a game of choice. When you make a merge commit, then you express "when I bring these branches together, the correct state of the project is the state in this commit". That is, if you make a merge, but undo part of it, module C i presume, then you say "nobody must ever have module C from now on".

@j6t yeah this was the kind of thinking that got me to ask the question in the first place. What course of action do you recommend, in light of that ?

@Charles Perhaps it is best that you do not ignore C?

What do you mean by "module"?  Git has a feature called "submodules", but I don't think you are referring to that.  Are you just using the word "module" to mean a portion of the directory tree?

Indeed, I only mean a couple of files in a folder.

Create a new branch from D
git checkout D
git checkout -b new-branch

Merge the relevant changes from H:
git merge --no-commit H

This will bring all changes from H into the new branch without committing.
Remove unwanted changes (module C):
Go through the changes and manually remove the modifications related to module
Commit the changes:
git commit -m "Update D with latest V and L, excluding C"

Merge the new branch into D:
git checkout D
git merge new-branch


What are the downsides ? Especially as regards a later merge of O into D ?

@Charles The excluded files are excluded and won't be merged by future merges either

@knittl Future merges e.g. from  O onto D/children of D1 ?

@Charles if you merge H into D and undo part of the changes (your "module C"), the later merges of successor commits of H will not merge "module C". Trying to merge O into D will not even create a merge request, because O was already merged (O is a predecessor of H). I'm not sure what happens when you create new commits off O and try to merge those. Probably lots of merge conflicts, because you try to merge something based on something else that doesn't exist in the target.

@knittl "O was already merged (O is a predecessor of H)" Good point, that's actually why I was asking all of this. More meditation is maybe required.
